# Complex analysis, P(z)

Tags: complex-analysis, polynomials

Show that for any polynomial P(z)
$max_{|z|=1}|\frac{1}{z^2} - P(z)| \geq 1$

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Assume that the maximum is $<1$. Then, on $|z|=1$ $|1/z^2-P(z)|<1=|1/z^2|$. Apply the [Argument principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_principle) together with this inequality to $1/z^2$ and $P$ to conclude that $1/z^2$ and $f$ have the same variation of the argument around $0$ along the loop $|z|=1$. But since this value is $-2$ for $1/z^2$, so should be for $P$. This implies that $P$ should have some poles inside $|z|<1$, which is a contradiction.

Comment: Essentially a duplicate of [Show that for any polynomial $p(z)$ there is a $z$ with $|z|=1$ such that $|p(z)-1/z|\geq 1$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/201529/show-that-for-any-polynomial-pz-there-is-a-z-with-z-1-such-that-pz).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Complex zeros of the polynomials $\sum_{k=0}^{n} z^k/k!$, inside balls](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/131479/complex-zeros-of-the-polynomials-sum-k-0n-zk-k-inside-balls)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume that the maximum is $<1$.

Then, on $|z|=1$ $|1/z^2-P(z)|<1=|1/z^2|$.

Neither $1/z^2$ nor $P$ has poles on $|z|=1$ and by the inequality $P$ doesn't vanish on $|z|=1$, nor does $1/z^2$. This allows us to use the [Argument principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_principle) to compute that $-2$ is the winding number of the image of the unit circle $|z|=1$ by $1/z^2$ around $0$.

Likewise, $0$ is the winding number of the image of $C$ by $P(z)$ around $0$.

Since $|1/z^2-P(z)|<1=|1/z^2|$, we have that $1/z^2$ is not a negative multiple of $P(z)$, for $|z|=1$. Therefore,

$$H(t,z)=t/z^2+(1-t)P(z)$$

provides a homotopy between those two curves that never touches $0$. Therefore, those two curves ought to have the same winding number with respect to $0$.

Contradiction.

---

Or you could apply [Rouche's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rouch%C3%A9%27s_theorem) to $1$ and $z^2P(z)$, since $$|z^2P(z)-1|<|z^{2}|=1$$
for $|z|=1$. The theorem implies that $1$ and $z^2P(z)$ have the same number of zeros inside $|z|<1$. But $1$ never vanishes and $z^2P(z)$ has two zeros in $|z|<1$.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the entire function $f(z)=1-z^2P(z)$. For $|z|=1$ we have

$$|\frac{1}{z^2} - P(z)| =|f(z)|.$$

Hence we have to show that $m:=\max \{|f(z)|: |z|=1\} \ge 1.$

If $M:=\max \{|f(z)|: |z| \le 1\}$, then the maximum - principle says:

$$M=m.$$

From  $|f(0)|=1$, we get  $M \ge1.$